# Redis backend in online using django

Tags: django, postgresql, redis, ubuntu-18.04, django-channels

I have create chat app, in offline it works fine, but when i deploy it online i receive this error

[image]

**note:** i have already install the redis without issue, this is my settings.py
this is production.py which is my another settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
        # "symmetric_encryption_keys": [SECRET_KEY],
    },
}
```

and this my settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

**note** my site is live

this is my referrence https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/ChatXChannels

**UPDATE**

when i run to ubuntu

$ redis-server

[image]

$ ps aux | grep redis-server

[image]

i still get this error

[image]

Comment: how are you running your server?

when running in production you should be running using `Daphne`

Comment: i run the server using redis

Comment: what is your startup command? `python manage.py` `daphne myserver.asgi:application` `gunicorn myserver.wsgi:application` ? or are you using uwsgi ?

Comment: python manage.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like your pre-existing Django server is handing your request rather than channels accepting the request.

I think your issue is in how you are running your server in production.

when running channels in production you have 2 choices.

1) Run all requests through Channels (even those being handled by your normal Django views)

2) Run both your normal server instance and your channels server instance (on different local ports) with some `path based reverse proxy` in-front of them (such as Nginx) that routs requests to the respective local port.

Regardless of the option you select you should be running channels in production using this Guide https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#run-protocol-servers (not python manager.py).

if you select option 1) then remember that when you run this you need it to run on the same port configuration as your old Django server used to run.

if you go with option 2) you should ensure that all of your traffic is first hitting your reverse proxy (Nginx) server. Then you can run `Daphne` on a different port and set up the routing in Nginx to proxy pass to the respective server instance depending on the path.

Comment: when using django channels redis is not responsible for handling your websocket connections. 

The daphne server handles this. The fact that you are getting `200` back when attempting to create a WS connection suggests that your request is not being routed to your websocket consumer within the channels server.

It uses redis to communicate between open connection.
-----------
Can you update your question to include how you are starting you django/django-channels server.

Comment: Thanks sir, i will try the daphne , i hope it goes well